# How to call Dojo method from inside function of another method?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here.

I want the `_webCall()` method to run once, so I have this IIFE function set up to run `fireFunc()`  which calls the `_webCall()` method, but it keeps saying `this._webCall(url)` is not a function.

I can't figure out what I have done wrong here. How can I call `_webCall()` from inside a function?

```
 _webCall: function(url){
        console.log(url)
      },

  onOpen: function(){
        var fireFunct = (function(){
          var url = 'someurl';
          var executed = false;
          return returnFunc(){
            if(!executed){
              executed = true;
              this._webCall(url);
            }
          }
        })();
        fireFunct();
      },
```

Comment: You need to use arrow functions instead, so `this` is still pointing to the instance (and not the wrapper function)

Comment: Oh, yep. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

In dojo there is a module that has the [hitch()](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch) function , which is dedicated to your case :

first import the `"dojo/_base/lang"` , then use the [lang.hitch()](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/_base/lang.html#hitch) function to point out the context of execution to this (which refers to your module )

```
require([.., "dojo/_base/lang", ...], function(.., lang, ...){
  
  //...


  _webCall: function(url){
    console.log(url)
  },
  
   
  onOpen: function(){
      var fireFunct =
      lang.hitch( this ,(function(){ // <--- execute function in the context of the module , this will point to the module not IFII function context
            var url = 'someurl';
            var executed = false;
            return returnFunc(){
               if(!executed){
                  executed = true;
                  this._webCall(url);
               }
            }
         })()
      );
      fireFunct();
  },


});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how you could do it without `hitch` using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
    onOpen: function(){
        const webCallFnc = this._webCall.bind(this);
        const fireFunct = (() => {
            const url = 'someurl';
            let executed = false;
            return () => {
                if(!executed){
                    executed = true;
                    webCallFnc(url);
                }
            }
        })();
        fireFunct();
    },
```